# How to use infobubble with geoxml3

Tags: infobubble, geoxml3

I am currently using the excellent [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) to parse local xml and kml files.  I wanted to try and make the infowindows more attractive (and also add tabs) and so I am trying to use the infobubble script. An example of what it looks like can be found [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/).

I have created a new parser with geoxml3 as follows:

```
var urlArray =[];
urlArray.push("pathto/data.xml");
urlArray.push("pathto/data2.xml");

var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    processStyles: true,
    infoWindowOptions : {maxWidth: 450},
    zoom:true,
    singleInfoWindow: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: true,

    afterParse: useTheData  
});    

myParser.parse(urlArray);
}
```

and then done the following to retrieve the marker object and the placemark description

```
    function useTheData(doc) {
    geoXmlDoc = doc;
    for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].markers.length; i++) {
        var marker = doc[0].markers[i];
        var placemark = doc[0].placemarks[i];
        markerMouseclick(marker,placemarks.description);
     }
    };
```

and then this to create the infobubble and the listener:

```
var ib = new InfoBubble({
          shadowStyle: 1,
          padding: 10,
          backgroundColor: '#AECAE8',
          borderRadius: 15,
          arrowSize: 0,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'red',
          disableAutoPan: false,
          hideCloseButton: false,
          arrowPosition: 50,
          arrowStyle: 0,
          arrowSize: 15,
          ShadowStyle: 1,
          minWidth: 300,
          maxWidth: 500,
          minHeight: 300,
          maxHeight: 500
        });

  function markerMouseclick(newmarker, text) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker,'click', function(evt) {
     ib.setContent(text);
     ib.setPosition(evt.latLng);
     ib.setMap(map);
     ib.open()
   });

}
```

The problem with this is the descriptions are now out of sync with the markers.  I have been searching for a way of adding a listener just using placemarks from the dom json geoXML3 doc passed by geoxml3 but I havent been able to do so and I cant find any description data in the markers branch.

I hope that this is clear despite my use of terms for these data structures that might be inaccurate.  Does anyone know how I can load my placemarks.descriptions into my infobubble instances so that they are displayed when the markers (rendered by geoxml3) are clicked?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a custom createMarker function (based on the native one) that uses infoBubble to display the content.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a custom createMarker function to hold closure on the marker and the infowindow content.

```
var ib = new InfoBubble({
          shadowStyle: 1,
          padding: 10,
          backgroundColor: '#AECAE8',
          borderRadius: 15,
          arrowSize: 0,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'red',
          disableAutoPan: false,
          hideCloseButton: false,
          arrowPosition: 50,
          arrowStyle: 0,
          arrowSize: 15,
          ShadowStyle: 1,
          minWidth: 300,
          maxWidth: 500,
          minHeight: 300,
          maxHeight: 500
        });

var M = null;
var P = null;

function I() {
 M = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('D'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.31,-0.36),
  zoom: 14
 });

function I() {    
 M = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('D'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.31,-0.36),
  zoom: 14
 });

 P = new geoXML3.parser({map:M, markerOptions: {
     icon:{
       url:'http://bus.w.pw/R.png',
       size:new google.maps.Size(9,9),
       anchor:new google.maps.Point(5,5)
     }
   }, 
   afterParse: S, 
   createMarker: CM, 
   suppressInfoWindows: true
 });
 P.parse('SO_20140226_bus_w_pw_TA.kml');
}

function S() {
 P.showDocument(P.docs[0]);
}

function CM(placemark) {
 var marker = P.createMarker(placemark);
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(E) {
     ib.setContent('Description : ' + placemark.description+"<br>"+'Latitude & longitude : ' + E.latLng);
     // ib.setPosition(evt.latLng);
     // ib.setMap(map);
     ib.open(M,marker)
   });
 return marker;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', I)
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_SO_geoxml3_customCreateMarkerInfoBubble.html)